# How to call a class so that a method performs specific operations based on variables in that class

Tags: java

I apologize greatly for the title, im open to sugguestions to rename it to something more clear

My problem is i have a task in which there are 3 seperate cards representing different membership statuses within a particular Shop. Theres a Basic card, silver card and a Gold card. Depending on the card different coupon is issued to the customer at the end of the Year. Right now im creating the coupon method within the main class. Im stuck on trying to get the method to work with the different ways each card operates.

In essence the method sees what card the customer has and applies the appropriate discount, for example if a customer is using a basic card and the balance(total spent) is more than $2000 then the coupon is 3%

Below is what i currently have(note im not worried about creating the 3 card classes, i just want to get one working)

```
    public class storeCard {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            cardDetails detailsObject1 = new cardDetails(0001, "Adam Gong", 7000);
            Date date = new Date(04, 8, 2019);
            storeCard store = new storeCard();
            basicCard card = new basicCard();

            System.out.println("***** Customer Details ******");
            System.out.println("Customers name: " + detailsObject1.getName());
            System.out.println("Customers ID: " + detailsObject1.getID());
            System.out.println("Customers balance: " + detailsObject1.getBalance());
            System.out.println("Created Date: " + date.getDay() + "/" + date.getMonth() + "/" + date.getYear());
            Address addressObject1 = new Address(63, "Boyd Street", "Eagle Vale", "Campbelltown", "NSW", 2558);

        }

        public void calCoupon(double balance) {

            if(balance < 2000);
            System.out.println("Coupon is 2%");


        }

    }
```

```
    import java.util.*;

class cardDetails {

    private int ID;
    private String name;
    private double balance;

    public cardDetails(int ID, String name, double balance) {

        this.ID = ID;
        this.name = name;
        this.balance = balance;

    }

    public int getID() {

        return this.ID;
    }

    public void setID(int customerID) {

        this.ID = customerID;

    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String customerName) {

        this.name = customerName;
    }

    public double getBalance() {
        return this.balance;
    }

    public void setBalance() {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

}
```

```
import java.util.*;

class Date {

    private int day, month, year;

    public Date(int day, int month, int year) {
        this.day = day;
        this.month = month;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public int getDay() {

        return this.day;
    }

    public void seDay(int Day) {

        this.day = day;

    }

    public int getMonth() {
        return this.month;
    }

    public void setMonth(int Month) {

        this.month = Month;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return this.year;
    }

    public void setYear(int Year) {
        this.year = Year;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return new String("date=" + day + ",month=" + month + ",year=" + year);

    }
}
```

```
  import java.util.*;

class Address {

    private int streetNumber;
    private String streetName;
    private String suburb;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private int postcode;

    public Address(int streetNumber, String streetName, String suburb, String city, String state, int postcode) {
        this.streetNumber = streetNumber;
        this.streetName = streetName;
        this.suburb = suburb;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.postcode = postcode;

        System.out.println("Customers Address: " + this);

    }

    public String toString() {
        return new String( streetNumber + " " +streetName + " " + suburb + " " + city + " " + state + " " + postcode);

    }
}
```

```
class basicCard { 
    final double discount = 0.03;
    double annuelFee = 10;
}
```

Comment: Side note, you do not have to implement your own `Date` class - have a look at [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class.

Comment: What is the **concrete** problem you're facing. "I'm stuck" or "get it working" doesn't tell us much. Also, it would be much easier for everyone, including you, if you posted the relevant code only, and if it reepcted the Java naming conventions.

Comment: First thing to fix: learn the syntax of an `if` statement. It's `if (condition) { instructions(); }`. Not `if (condition); instructions();`

Comment: @JBNizet im unsure of the coupon aspect once theres more than one class. I assume you call the balance method in each class and then call the respesctive class in the calcoupon method in order to get the correct coupon for the correct card.

Comment: I don't know. I have no idea of which classes you're talking about. None of the classes you posted has a balance method. `calCoupon` doesn't mean anything to me, and it has no doumentation, so it's quite hard for us to guess what it's supposed to do. It belongs to a class named `storeCard`, but once again, what is a `storeCard`? No idea.

Comment: @AndrewVan Thank you for discarding my edit. I thought it was a good one...

Comment: @JBNizet apologies, ive updated my source code i thought i uploaded it all.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Editing is async--if two people are editing a question at the same time sometimes one gets eaten. Please don't jump straight to assuming bad intentions and snark.

Comment: @michalk in regards to the localDate class. Would i be able to do a date the account was created minus the current date?

Answer (score 5):

It's not entirely clear if this is what you're asking, but you probably want to create an `interface` for what the card does and let the concrete cards implement it.

```
interface Card {
    double getDiscount(double moneySpent);
}

class BasicCard implements Card {
    public double getDiscount(double spent) {
        return spent < 2000d ? 0 : 3;
    }
}

class SilverCard implements Card {
    public double getDiscount(double spent) {
        return spent < 2000d ? 1 : 5;
    }
}

class PremiumCard implements Card {
    public double getDiscount(double spent) {
        return spent < 2000d ? 3 : 8;
    }
}
```

Then the money spent in total is

```
double baseAmount = 2500; // for example
double total = baseAmount - (customer.getCard().getDiscount(baseAmount) * baseAmount);
```

You probably don't really need subclasses but can use factory methods.

```
class Cards {
    public static Card basicCard() {
        return amount -> amount < 2000d ? 0 : 3;
    }
    public static Card silverCard() {
        return amount -> amount < 2000d ? 1 : 5;
    }
    public static Card basicCard() {
        return amount -> amount < 2000d ? 5 : 8;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Card` holds `discount` and `annual fee` (plus a function to calculate a coupon), I think an enum would be appropriate

Comment: @AndrewTobilko apologies, ive updated my source code i thought i uploaded it all.

Comment: @daniu  apologies, ive updated my source code i thought i uploaded it all.

Comment: @AndrewVan the problem with the card holding just a discount number is that it falls short if it's dependent on the silent amount that can differ between cards. It doesn't really matter though, I think that's just a detail and my reply answers the main point of your question.

Comment: @daniu The discount is a final double type. Im trying to calculate the coupon

Comment: @daniu there is a second part in which you find the amount of years someone has been a member for but im doing that later

Answer (score 0):

You have two information : 
The `CardDetail` that conveys the details of the card (id, name, balance) and the type of card.

A simple approach would be to specify a card type field in `CardDetails` and to introduce an enum which each value will store these data :

```
class BasicCard { 
    final double discount = 0.03;
    double annuelFee = 10;
}
```

`CardDetails` would be :

```
public class CardDetails {

    public static enum CardType{
        BASIC(0.03, 10), SILVER(0.05, 15), GOLD(0.1, 20);

        final double discount;
        final double annuelFee;

        CardType(double discount, int annuelFee) {
            this.discount = discount;
            this.annuelFee = annuelFee;
        }

       public double getDiscount(){
           return discount;
      }
    }

    private int ID;
    private String name;
    private double balance;
    private CardType cardType;

    // constructors, getters
    ...
   double applyDiscount(double productPrice){
      return productPrice * (1 - cardType.getDiscount());
   }

}
```

Then you can use all of these as:

```
CardDetails cardDetailsFoo = new CardDetails(0001, "Adam Gong", 7000, CardDetails.CardType.BASIC);
double productPrice = ...;
double discountPrice = cardDetailsFoo.applyDiscount(productPrice);
```

Note that for more precise computations, you should favor `BigDecimal` over `double`.

Comment: they want us to treat the card types as 3 seperate classes